# Using automapper with PagedList.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, pagedlist

I am trying to convert to using ViewModels in my mvc4 application. I have successfully switched my POST actions to use viewmodels, but in the below example, I am trying to use both automapper and PagedList in an action.

I have made a class called AutoMapperConfiguration (below) to avoid adding mapping throughout the application:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ConfigureItemMapping();
    }

    public class PagedListConverter : ITypeConverter<PagedList<Item>,PagedList<ItemListViewModel>>
    {
        public PagedList<ItemListViewModel> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var model = (PagedList<Item>)context.SourceValue;
            var vm = model.Select(m => Mapper.Map<Item, ItemListViewModel>(m)).ToPagedList(model.PageNumber,model.PageSize);

            return new PagedList<ItemListViewModel>(vm,model.PageNumber,model.PageSize);
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureItemMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemListViewModel,Item>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PagedList<Item>, PagedList<ItemListViewModel>>()
            .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>();
    }
}
```

The above is called from Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
     {
       ...
       AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
       ...
     }
```

From the controller, I am trying to send a list of items to the itemViewModel from the item Model as a Paged List. This is where I have become completely stuck. Needless to say the below doesn't work.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
        {
            //Show 10 items per page for the Admin
            int pageSize = 10;

            var items = new PagedList<Item>(
                        db.Items.OrderBy(i => i.ItemId),page,pageSize);
            var vm = new ItemListViewModel();

            Mapper.Map<PagedList<Item>, PagedList<ItemListViewModel>>(items);

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Error now being seen is:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Item -> ItemListViewModel Project.Models.Item ->
>   Project.ViewModels.ItemListViewModel
>
> Destination path: ItemListViewModel

It is being thrown on the following line in the PagedListConverter

```
 var vm = model.Select(m => Mapper.Map<Item, ItemListViewModel>(m)).ToPagedList(model.PageNumber,model.PageSize);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `PagedList<Item>` manually and then map to a `PagedList<ItemViewModel>`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
{
    int pageSize = 20;

    var vm = new ItemListViewModel();
    var items = new PagedList(
        db.Items.OrderBy(i => i.ItemId),
        page,
        pageSize);

    var viewModels = Mapper.Map<PagedList<Item>, PagedList<ItemListViewModel>>(items);

    return View(viewModels);
}
```

Then it also seems like your converter needs some tweaks too. It should probably take the page number and size from the source `PagedList`:

```
public class PagedListConverter : ITypeConverter<PagedList<Item>,PagedList<ItemListViewModel>>
{
    public PagedList<ItemListViewModel> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var model = (PagedList<Item>)context.SourceValue;
        var vm = model.Select(m => Mapper.Map<Item, ItemListViewModel>(m)).ToList();

        return new PagedList<ItemListViewModel>(vm, model.PageNumber, model.PageSize);
    }
}
```

Also make sure to use your custom converter when you call `CreateMap`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PagedList<Item>, PagedList<ItemViewModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>();
```

You also need a map from `Item` to `ItemViewModel`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemListViewModel>();
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have looked at your example code and amended accordingly to test. But I am getting an error in the PagedListConverter (in the original post).

Comment: @user2317406: I think you have your mapping backwards: you need one from `Item` to `ItemListViewModel`. I've updated the answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the following: var vm = new ItemListViewModel(); in the controller. Should this not need to be converted to a PagedList also?

Comment: I'm not sure you even need `vm`. I don't know what you're passing to the view, but could you just use `items` instead?

Comment: I am trying to pass the Viewmodel to the view rather than the model. Along these lines, I thought I would have to pass 'vm' as opposed to 'items'. If I pass items to the view, would I not be passing the view the model rather than the VM?

Comment: @user2317406: Sorry, you're right--I should have typed `viewModels` (I've updated the answer). That way you're passing a list of view models to the view.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks a lot for your help. For the most part it seems to be working now; Now just showing the first 20 results and not creating new pages. Ill have a play with that.

Answer (score 4):

Generic solution in AutoMapper 6+:

TypeConverter:

```
public class PagedListConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<PagedList<TSource>, PagedList<TDestination>> where TSource : class where TDestination : class
{
    public PagedList<TDestination> Convert(PagedList<TSource> source, PagedList<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var collection = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(source.Value);

        return new PagedList<TDestination>(collection, source.Page, source.Size, source.TotalCount);
    }
}
```

Initialize:

```
CreateMap(typeof(PagedList<>), typeof(PagedList<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(PagedListConverter<,>));
```

Example:

```
var vm = Mapper.Map<PagedList<User>, PagedList<UserViewModel>>(users);
```

**UPDATE:**

If u are using dependency injection (IMapper), then replace the static class `Mapper` with the `context.Mapper.Map...`

```
var collection = context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(source.Items);
```